# Can't work out why it's telling me no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, angular, cors

I'm trying to connect an Angular form to a phpmail file. There's no problem when the angular files are compiled and uploaded as a webapp alongside the php file. But if they're anywhere else I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com/sendEmail.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Having looked this up quite a lot everyone is saying to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which I've done. But it's still saying the same.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
switch ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] ) {
  case ( "OPTIONS" ): 
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" );
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AccountKey, x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, host, date, cookie, cookie2" );
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" );
    header( "Content-Type: application/json");
    
    exit;
  case ( "POST" ): 

    $json = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );

    $params = json_decode( $json, TRUE );

    // Do all the things necessary here to send the email

    break;
  default: 
    header( "Allow: POST", true, 405 );
    exit;
}
?>
```

I'm obviously missing something but I have no idea what. Do I need to put something in the angular file as well? I assumed not as the console error says that it's not present in the requested resource. But it is, isn't it?

Edit:

As requested here is the (abbreviated) version of the angular code to call the php file in the first place.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.num1 = this.getRandomArbitrary(2, 10);
    this.num2 = this.getRandomArbitrary(2, 10);
    this.solution = this.num1 + this.num2;


    this.endpoint = "https://www.example.com/sendEmail.php";

    
    this.contactUs = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [''],
      surname: [''],
      companyName: [''],
      jobTitle: [''],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      telephone: [''],
      enquiry: [''],
      userSolution: ['', [Validators.required, this.myValidator(this.solution)]],
    });
  }

  submitForm() {

    let postVars = this.contactUs.value;


    
    postVars['recipientEmail'] = this.email;
    postVars['subject'] = this.subject;
    // console.log(postVars);


    this.http.post(this.endpoint, postVars)
      .subscribe((val) => {
        if (val == null) {
          this.contactUs.reset();
          this.presentToast();
        }
      },
        response => {
          console.log("POST call in error", response);
        },
        () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
        })
  }
```

Looking in Network I'm seeing that sendEmail.php is getting a 403 error in the preflight. Here's a screenshot:

[image: devtools network screenshot]

network headers:

```
General:
    Request URL: https://www.websitesberkshire.co.uk/sendEmail.php
    Request Method: OPTIONS
    Status Code: 403 Forbidden
    Remote Address: [my server ip]:443
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers:
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 318
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    Date: Mon, 15 Mar 2021 12:13:40 GMT
    Server: Apache

Request Headers:
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
    Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Host: www.example.com
    Origin: http://localhost:8100
    Pragma: no-cache
    Referer: http://localhost:8100/
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Well, use the Network tool look at the response which actually comes back. Presumably it still doesn't have those headers. Now ask yourself why. Perhaps the PHP code isn't being executed - .e.g. maybe the webserver returns something else instead before the request gets to PHP? Have you debugged what actually happens to your OPTIONS request?

Comment: It would also help if you show us how you're generating the request in the JS/Angular code, just in case anything isn't quite right with that.

Comment: Also put the headers in the post request.

Comment: @Daantje valid point, but we haven't even got that far yet, that isn't the OP's problem at the moment.

Comment: If the php file sits alongside the webapp it works flawlessly and sends the email, it's when the webapp hasn't been uploaded to the server and is still running off my localhost do i get the issue. I've edited my post and included more stuff in the hope that someone may know the solution as it's currently driving me mad.

Comment: Looks like you're getting a 403 on the OPTIONS request...this suggests maybe your webserver config doesn't permit OPTIONS requests. It's like the request never reaches PHP (did you try and ascertain that, as I suggested?)

Comment: OPTIONS requests are fairly new to me at this stage so I wouldn't actually know how to debug it. I do have a dedicated server running WHM so I can fully go into the back end, just wouldn't have a clue how to allow OPTIONS requests in the first place (if indeed that's the issue here)

Comment: `I do have a dedicated server running WHM`...in your localhost, you mean? Anyway it's probably Apache specifically which is blocking it. So google how to allow OPTIONS requests in Apache and you're probably on the right track. P.S. in the Network tab of your browser, If you click on that request which receives the 403 and examine the full response and the full headers, you might potentially get more clues about the source of it.

Comment: I mean an actual dedicated rented server on a server farm running Apache with WHM and cPanel. Post is further edited to display network headers. Hopefully I've included the required info

Comment: `I mean an actual dedicated rented server on a server farm running Apache with WHM and cPanel`...ok but you said the issue is only happening on your localhost, so the content of your other server isn't hugely relevant as far as I can see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229931/discussion-between-jimbeeer-and-adyson).

Comment: `Server: Apache` confirms it's Apache at least. So yes you need to go and find out how to enable OPTIONS requests in Apache. I can't remember exactly what you need to do off the top of my head, but you won't be the first person to have asked it by a long way.

Comment: so it turns out that OPTIONS is already allowed on my server. Back to square 1 it looks like!

Comment: What evidence has been provided for that? The 403 response says otherwise. You need to add some simple logging to the PHP file, so you can debug whether the request is actually hitting your PHP code or not. If it isn't getting as far as the first line of the PHP script, then that indicates the issue is likely to be within Apache. You should also have access to the Apache logs for your account through cPanel, so you should be able to see the OPTIONS request logged, and what response Apache gave to it.